# Mysql delete all rows (where col != this or col != that or col != otherthing)

Tags: mysql

I am having trouble writing a query. Lets say I have a table full car makes and models, but I want to get rid of all of rows that are not associated with a list of models, I have written this...

```
DELETE FROM `cars` WHERE 
`make` != 'Ford' OR
`make` != 'Toyota' OR
`make` != 'Cadillac'
```

However it is removing all of the rows. How do I write this so that I keep Ford, Toyota and Cadiillac, but delete Pontiac, Datsun and Renault?

Thank you for your help on this!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Easier to read:

```
DELETE FROM `cars` WHERE `make` NOT IN ('Ford', 'Toyota', 'Cadillac')
```

Answer (score 4):

```
DELETE FROM cars
WHERE make <> 'Ford'
AND make <> 'Toyota'
AND make <> 'Cadillac'
```

Your query was removing all rows because:

1. You were first removing all rows that were not Ford (leaves only Ford)
2. You were then removing all rows that were not Toyota (leaves nothing)